# Failed run (hang) 16-bit setup.exe (InstallShiled) on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, installshield, ntvdm

Old 16-bit `setup.exe` in Windows XP can not run. In `Task Manager` you can see `ntvdm.exe`, `wowexec.exe` and `setup.exe`. But it nothing do, only stay in process list.

For me it happens for InstallShield installer of `1С:7.7`. But it can be for any 16-bit installer.

In safe mode of Windows XP setup.exe must run normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need check next things:
1. Set in registry param `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\WOW` to `yes` if it set to `no`.
2. Go to `TEMP` folder and delete all entries which possible.
3. Open `Task Manager` and kill all not necessary processes. Leave only system processes.

**3 item is most important.** Some application can use some resources and prevent work `setup.exe` normally.

As far as I know problems can be if run some of `Nero Scout` processes (`NMBgMonitor`). But not only its. In my case it be something other.

Others solutions from internet:

1:

> I had this exact problem and searched high and low. After playing with
>   Process Explorer from Microsoft I found a print screen utility was
>   keeping my Setup.exe from running. After killing it everything worked
>   great. Not sure of the true root cause however. Here is the program
>   that was causing the hang-up.
>
> http://software.techrepublic.com.com/abstract.aspx?docid=740263

2:

> The solution on my system was to disable zonealarm, i think it blocked
>   some processes because it was corrupted.

3:

> And now I have solved it:
>   - I turned off Norton Antivirus.